# Changes to PostgreSQL source code

Tags: postgresql, systems-programming

I was working around with Postgres a bit. I am trying to get familiar to editing the source code of the same.

One of the suggested exercise was to change the buffer replacement policy of the system of Postgres 7.4. (It was in one of the homeworks of some university. First few links of google. I am just using them to get familiar to the code.)

I understand parts of it but I am not able to fully understand how to modify the system. I mean, I know the particular files,buffer folder files in the src/backend/storage location as the files where I have to make changes, but how to implement my own scheme and test it, is going over my head.

So my question is, can anyone help me with some basic code snippet understanding? (Probably, give me idea how to solve the question mentioned above? and how to test it ( most important). ) (This is not a homework of any sort, promise. I am just trying to get a hang of things.)

If not, can anyone refer me to some book which can help me with modification of the postgresql source code? There are books to use postgresql, but I couldn't find any that could help to modify the source code.

P.S: I know the online documentation of PGSQL source code resides at: http://doxygen.postgresql.org/

But I am not able to understand a lot from there. I need a book that can help the layman!

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the [Developer FAQ](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Developer_FAQ) your best starting point will be the PostgreSQL mailing lists.

You might start with posting to http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-novice/ ("*No question is too simple for this list*")

And if you really start changing the source code you will need to subscribe to http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-hackers/ as well.

And don't use the 7.x source code. PostgreSQL is at Version 9.1 now and I'm sure studying the ancient history won't be very helpful.

Comment: I agree on studying newer versions, however what might prove useful is comparing sections of the code from an older version to a newer version.  A lot of interesting things have happened between the old 7.4 version and the newer versions, so a diff of certain parts of the old and new versions should prove interesting.